# Can't reference System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, exception

I'm trying to catch this exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
```

But visual studio isn't finding it.  There's no little red dash at the end, and if I try doing a using on the `System.ServiceModel` namespace, there is no ServiceModel in System.  Though from [System.ServiceModel Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) it is in the .Net Framework class library.

Is there a reason I cannot reference it?

I get the error when my application cannot access my web-service.

**Edit**:
Target framework is: 3.5
Client framework is not checked.

**Edit**:  I'd added the System.ServiceModel namespace, but apparently (it wasn't obvious at the time), I'd added it to a class library instead of the program.  That was the whole bother.  When suggested that I close and start a new project, add the library, it worked, so I went back and looked.  VS was different on re-open and it was obvious I'd added System.ServiceModel to the library and not the main project.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you targeting the Client Profile version of the Framework? Perhaps this class is not provided there.

Comment: Huh?  I don't know what you mean, "targeting the Client Profile."

Comment: Versions 3.5 and 4.0 of the .NET FW have a special "Client Profile" edition that's supposed to provide a smaller download. It does this by removing lesser-used pieces of the framework. You can change which version of the FW you target in your project's Properties. I'm not sure if this class is excluded in the Client Profile, but it might be, and that could certainly explain your problem.

Comment: Ok, I see the checkbox for Client-only Framework subset, but it is clear/not-checked.

Comment: Well nuts, that was the simplest answer. If you've *definitely* added the reference, and you're *definitely* targeting .NET 3.0+, then this *will* work. I just created a new project targeting .NET 3.5 (full) in VS 2008, added the reference to `System.ServiceModel`, and everything works as expected. Something else is wrong. Try seeing if you can do the same thing in a new, blank project.

Comment: Ok, thanks - that did it.  I thought of doing the same, and yes it works... (Going back and checking, the view in VS was different and I saw) I'd added System.ServiceModel to a library, instead of the main project.  Thanks for sticking with me on that.  User error once again, mind copying your last comment to an answer so I can mark as accept?

Comment: @Chuck: No problem; glad you got it to work. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Added at the request of the asker, in response to discussions in comments.)</sup>

If you've *definitely* added the reference, and you're *definitely* targeting .NET 3.0+, then this *will* work.

I just created a new project targeting .NET 3.5 (full) in VS 2008, added the reference to `System.ServiceModel`, and everything works exactly as expected.

Something else must be wrong. Try seeing if you can do the same thing in a new, blank project.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding the assembly reference to `System.ServiceModel` to your project?

**Edit** Just in case this is the issue, here's instructions on how to do so:

- [How To: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Either I just added it, or it was already there - in either case, it isn't helping.

Answer (score 3):

Two requirements:

- Add a reference to System.ServiceModel.dll
- Target .NET framework 3.0 or higher

The latter is probably your issue.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Target framework setting in the C# IDE.

Comment: Update your question with this essential info.

Answer (score 0):

Add Reference to SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL

I had this same problem, I had a VS2012 win forms project .NET 3.5 client profile. 
I wanted to integrate with UPS API via VS2010 Console project .NET 3.5
I hacked it apart, grabbed a dll and the pertianent .cs page... it was using System.ServiceModel but my VS2012 project did not understand this...

Adding a reference to SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL solved this for me

- version:3.0.0.0
- path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client\System.ServiceModel.dll